# Linq to SQL Make dependency on filtered table (with view?)

Tags: linq-to-sql, dependencies

OK here it goes:

I am programming a website in Asp.net MVC.

I've used the Users tables and all those extra tables which come with Asp.net for logging in, ...

Now, these users have roles. 1 of the roles is `Teacher`, other roles are `Admin, Manager, ...`

I have a table called `Lessons`

Each lesson has 1 or more teacher. In the old DB there was a teacher table, connected to the lessons table via a subtable to have a more on more relationship.

Now i'd like to have a View or something which consists of all my users which have the "teacher" role. Uptill here i can do it myself.

BUT, is it possible to have a dependency on a view so that my teachers and lessons are interconnected in my DBML file, or is there an other way?

how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq to SQL, you can create a view in your database, and drag it into your .DBML and query it the usual way. And, if you want the view to have a relationship to another table, you can manually create the associations in the DBML designer.

Comment: I've created an association but in my code it doesn't show the view as being connected to my table. From an object of my table i can't 'select' the associated objects from my view...

Comment: it seems the view needs a PK, then it works :) easy to do in the DBML. Thanks!